# How to get the correct sum for two columns using case when

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, case, union

I am working on a program that will track a salespersons sold units, these units can be full deals (1) or half deals (0.5). What I need to do is find a way to get the SUM of the full deals and the half deals grouped by a salespersons ID.

Here is the database structure:

| id | salesperson_id | salesperson_two_id | sold_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | null | 2022-07-02 |
| 2 | 3 | 5 | 2022-07-18 |
| 3 | 4 | null | 2022-07-16 |
| 4 | 5 | 3 | 2022-07-12 |
| 5 | 3 | 5 | 2022-07-17 |
| 6 | 5 | null | 2022-07-18 |

I have a query that works if I only want to retrieve the SUM for one salesperson:

```
SELECT 
SUM(case when salesperson_id = 5 and isnull(salesperson_two_id) then 1 end) as fullDeals, 
SUM(case when salesperson_id != 5 and salesperson_two_id = 5 
or salesperson_id = 5 and salesperson_two_id != 5 then 0.5 end) as halfDeals 
FROM sold_logs WHERE MONTH(sold_date) = 07 AND YEAR(sold_date) = 2022;
```

Output would be as expected:

| fullDeals | halfDeals |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 1.5 |

What I am trying to accomplish is get these results for all salespeople in the table and have no clue how to make it happen. Here is what I am trying to get in the results:

| salesperson_id | totalDeals |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | 3.5 |
| 3 | 1.5 |
| 4 | 1 |

I would like the results sorted by totalDeals if at all possible.

Comment: Why does salesperson #4 have a full deal when his counterparty is null?

Comment: Start with this [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=df60801ce37e7c8c103faf8ffa218829), which is easier to read (in my opinion) then the complex (`salesperson_id != 5 and salesperson_two_id = 5 
or salesperson_id = 5 and salesperson_two_id != 5`) which might only be valid for person=5

Comment: Be careful when you mix AND/OR in the same sentence, you may need to use ()

Comment: BTW:  0.5 halfDeals , how many deals would that be....  

Comment: Your design really needs to be normalised - what happens when you need `salesperson_three_id` then `saleperson_thirty_id` etc Even with just two a normalised design would make your querying simpler.

Comment: @Stu There will never be an instance where there needs to be more than 2 salespeople in this particular system.

Comment: @Luuk I use a variable to pass the salesperson_id into the query. I hard coded the ID in this case to show what I was looking for as a result. and 0.5 half deals is a split deal between two salespeople, each getting half the credit.

Comment: @RayC:  When naming a variable it's not very smart to name it "half.."  this gets confusing at some point, but that only my opinion, so ... no worries!

Comment: @Luuk The variables I use to pass the ID's are not named half. Not sure where you got that from. And returning results as halfDeals and fulldeals, makes complete sense if you knew the details of the system that is being built. Due to the simple fact, that is the verbiage used when referring to deals in the industry this is written for. However, you are right using a variable named 'half' wouldn't be very smart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `UNION ALL` to get a resultset with all the rows for each salesperson, filter for the month that you want and aggregate:

```
SELECT salesperson_id,
       SUM(CASE WHEN salesperson_two_id IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0.5 END) totalDeals
FROM (
  SELECT salesperson_id, salesperson_two_id, sold_date FROM sold_logs
  UNION ALL
  SELECT salesperson_two_id, salesperson_id, sold_date FROM sold_logs WHERE salesperson_two_id IS NOT NULL
) t
WHERE MONTH(sold_date) = 7 AND YEAR(sold_date) = 2022
GROUP BY salesperson_id
ORDER BY totalDeals DESC;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4e982b18a6396025121c3fe4031b97df).